# Efficient way to keep a count of entries within a timeframe? e.g. How many actions did user do in the last 7 days

Tags: postgresql

I track user events - say, clicks - and would like to show them how often they've clicked in the last week, last 30 days, etc. So of course, as time progresses, that number needs to be updated.

Here is my naive attempt at just computing the number in a query:

Table format:

```
table_name
timestamp | timestamp with time zone
user_id | integer
```

Each row in the table represents another instance of the user event being logged.

The query I have right now:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table_name WHERE user_id = 1 
  AND timestamp >= NOW() - '7 days'::interval;
```

This works fine, especially with a bit of caching thrown in, but as someone who doesn't understand much about database internals, I have to wonder if there isn't a more efficient way than having to do a SELECT with a date comparison filter every time. Neither column here is indexed. So I'm curious, is there a better way? Like some special data type or something. Are there any problems with running a query like this frequently as the number of entries increases dramatically? Or is this actually the most common way to do it?

Comment: I've never used it, but you could look at the community edition of TimescaleDB - I did a search for `time series databases postgres` and there are several articles which might be of interest to you - there's also InfluxDB - search for `list of time series databases`, but if you're familiar with PostgreSQL, my **IMPRESSION** is that it might be a very good place to start - you get [a lot](https://www.timescale.com/products) of functionality with the Open Source edition - again, I stress, this is just a suggestion from what I have read - I have no experience in the domain!

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty common way of doing things, and PostgreSQL is designed to handle aggregative queries for large datasets very well. Though adding an index on the user_id and timestamp columns would improve performance, if you have that ability.

Comment: That's the first I've ever heard of PostgreSQL having `columnstore storage` - it's my understanding that PostgreSQL uses the classic row-based storage - an internet search of `postgresql column based storage` shows that while there are PG c-based storage systems/projects out there, it is certainly **NOT** the default of the standard PostgreSQL install!

Comment: @Verace Yes sorry I just learned this is not true in out of the box PostgreSQL but is an extension. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Having neither column be indexed is probably not so common.  I would generally expect at least user_id to be indexed.  And if that is good enough, it is good enough.  You could make it faster by having an index on `(user_id, timestamp)` and keep the table vacuumed well enough for index-only-scans to be efficient.  If (and preferably only if) that proves too slow, you could look into things like column store extensions, or partially aggregating the data.